# Need a second level menu

Tags: activeadmin

Does activeadmin support 2nd level menus? For example, I tried the following to have "Safety" under "Resources" and "Cyber Security" and "Emergency Plans" under "Safety"

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Safety' do
  menu parent:'Resources'
  content do
    render template: 'safety/safety'
  end
end


ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Cyber Security' do
  menu parent: 'Safety'
  content do
    render template: 'safety/cyber_security'
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Emergency Plans' do
  menu parent: 'Safety'
  content do
    render template: 'safety/emergency_plans'
  end
end
```

That does not work. I simply see the Safety menu item in the dropdown but I don't see the other three We are using version 0.6.6 of activeadmin.

Question: Does this version or any newer version of active-admin support multi level menus? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It has limited support with a feature called `navigation menu`, see the [docs on belongs_to](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to). 
 Beyond that, but take a look at [active_admin-subnav](https://github.com/zorab47/active_admin-subnav)  I hope you will consider ActiveAdmin 1.x for newer versions of Rails.